# How does Hessian matrix describe the local curvature?

Tags: calculus

For a 2-variable function $f(x,y)$, the Hessian matrix is
$$\mathcal{H}(f) = \left[\begin{array}{cc} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial {xy}} \\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial {xy}} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\end{array}\right]$$,
how does it describe the local curvature of $f$?

Answer (score 4):

Are you familiar with the Taylor expansion of a single variable function?$$f(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)\Delta x+\frac12f''(x_0)\Delta x^2+\dots$$We can also find Taylor expansions for multivariable functions; the first two terms should be familiar:$$f(\mathbf{x})=f(\mathbf{x}_0)+J(\mathbf{x}_0)\Delta\mathbf{x}+\frac12\Delta\mathbf{x}^TH(\mathbf{x}_0)\Delta\mathbf{x}+\dots$$... so we see that while the Jacobian corresponds to our original idea of the *derivative*, the Hessian instead serves a purpose like our *second derivative* -- it indeed captures local curvature information. In fact, if you look at its elements, this should become very clear.

Comment: I know Taylor expansion, and I know that for a single variable function, its curvature is $\kappa=\frac{|f''|}{(1+f'^2)^{3/2}}$, but I don't know what does the curvature for 2-variable functions look like.

Comment: http://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node32.html#eqn:surf_explicit_K

Comment: I still don't understand why Hessian captures the local curvature info, just because it encodes the second derivative? Moreover, to compute the curvature, we need both first and second derivatives, right?

Comment: The second derivative itself doesn't exactly encode 'curvature' - as loganecolss points out, you need the first and second derivative for that. Rather, the second derivative should be better thought of as a measure of the concavity/convexity of the function. (Think back to the classic second derivative test for maxima/minima).

Comment: @BaronMingus, each entry in Hessian matrix is just a 2nd order derivative, which indicates how fast the 1st order derivative changes in x or y axis, right? So I can understand the 2nd order derivatives show the concavity/convexity.

Comment: well just as the curvature $\kappa$ relies on $f',f''$ so does the extrinsic curvature surface rely on $f_x,f_y,f_{xx},f_{xy},f_{yy}$

Comment: @loganecolss yes, in the sense that concavity tells you the way the curve bends; a curve bending 'upwards' has positive curvature whereas a curve bending 'downwards' has negative curvature. The partial derivatives give you similar information along different axes.